# A complicated equation system

Tags: puzzle, transcendental-equations

Are you up for a challange? Nine years ago, I experimented with some variables and came up with an equation system. I figured out there were solutions to it and worked hard to find generalized ways to solve for the different variables. I only used a note pad, pen and an ordinary "high school" calculator with the most basic stuff on it like logaritms, cosine and so on.

This is the system in question: $$z=x^2-y^2=xy=(x-y)^z $$

Can you solve it without plotting graphs on a calculator (in which case it is not much of a challange)? I don't remember exactly how I solved it, becuase it invloed a lot of testing, intution and homemade numerical methods. If you find solutions it will be interesting to see in what form you present them. Becuase they can be expressed in many different ways, I suspect.

This is way over my head to take on myself, but after we have the solutions with as many decimals as we find suitable the question also arises whether we can prove that the variables are transcendental numbers. (I suppose they are.)

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to solve the relationship for $(x,y)$, then it's easy to compute and check the $z$ from there. You have 
$$
x^2-y^2=xy\\
y^2+xy-x^2=0
$$
and now the quadratic formula yields
$$
y_\pm = \frac{-x \pm \sqrt{x^2+4x^2}}{2} = x \left(\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}\right).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Exactly! And that was a very neat way to show the relationship.

If x=y=0, z is not equal to 0 for x^2-y^2=xy=(x-y)^z . I think I started with z=0, when xy=1. From there I generalized the case for z and came up with the following relatinship: Let a=(2z-1)/(z-2), z is not equal to 2. Therefore: (z=(2a-1)/(a-2), a is not equal to 2. Then x1=((1+sqrt(5))/2)^a and y1=((1+sqrt(5))/2)^(a-1) If z is an integer we also have: for even z: x2=-((1+sqrt(5))/2)^a y2=-((1+sqrt(5))/2)^(a-1) and for odd z: x2=-((sqrt(5)-1)/2)^a and y2=((sqrt(5)-1)/2)^(a-1)

I am skipping steps here, but returning to the original z=x^2-y^2=xy=(x-y)^z : by now I already knew that ((ln z)(4/z-2))/ln((3-sqrt(5))/2)=3 after some previous manipulation.  From here, I used numerical methods.  I got z1=7.30220780349213621366538204...  and z2=0.565797562941563696922557253... From there:

x1=3.437327511158194756287987239599091116665455... y1=2.124385232360847796318777545089287738785702... x2=0.956807027352594226892051778700936525639314... y2=0.591339263578653552729527217298789716342087...

Due to the nature of the logarithmic equation, I think z must be a positive real number. If only one of x and y is not a real number then xy should not be a real number. But if neither where real numbers, then x-y should not be a real number either. So, I don't think there are any other solutions.